# Is it possible to download files from a TravisCI worker's file system to local disk?

Tags: phantomjs, travis-ci

I'm attempting to run a visual diff using PhantomJS on Travis-CI. The test fails with [the following error](https://travis-ci.org/danvk/codediff.js/builds/33742446):

```
test failed
  0.188123 distortion
  Ref:  /tmp/tmpaVuhik/tmpg6uSXl/ref_resized
  Run:  /tmp/tmpaVuhik/tmpg6uSXl/screenshot.png
  Diff: /tmp/tmpaVuhik/tmpg6uSXl/diff.png
```

The visual differ has helpfully put the expected screenshot, the actual screenshot and a perceptual diff in PNG files on local disk on the Travis worker. What would be great is if I could see them!

Is it possible to download files from the Travis worker's disk to my local disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [travis-artifacts](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-artifacts) for uploading files produced by running tests. Currently it supports only uploading to Amazon S3.

Comment: This seems like the simplest general solution. In practice, since my build artifacts were all images, I added a --imgur flag which uploaded them to imgur.com: https://github.com/bslatkin/dpxdt/pull/101

Answer (score 0):

You can scp the artefacts to your own server. With commercial travis they provide a private key that you can use to identify the build (add the corresponding public key to the authorized_keys in the target server). With travis-ci.org you can do it in a much dodgier way.

(Please read everything down to the caveats before starting.)

- Generate a public-private pair of keys. You will use that to allow the Travis build to authenticate itself and give it access to your server.

  ```
  ssh-keygen -f build_id_rsa -P ''
  ```
- Append the public key to the authorized_keys in the target server.

  ```
  $ scp build_id_rsa.pub user@server:.
  user@sever's password:
  build_id_rsa.pub
  $ ssh user@server
  [...]
  $ mkdir .ssh
  $ cat build_id_rsa.pub >>.ssh/authorized_keys
  $ exit
  ```
- Generate a known_hosts by logging in with an ad hoc known_hosts file. When asked, assuming that you are happy with the fingerprint, enter *yes*

  ```
  $ ssh -i build_id_rsa -oUserKnownHostsFile=build_known_hosts -oPasswordAuthentication=no user@server
  The authenticity of host [...] can't be established.
  ECDSA key fingerprint is [...]
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
  Warning: Permanently added 'server,[...]' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
  Welcome to [...]
  user@server:~$ exit
  logout
  Connection to server closed.
  ```
- If you now repeat the same command you can test that we have correctly set up the keys and the known_host. This time it should log you in without any questions, neither confirmation nor password.

  ```
  $ ssh -i build_id_rsa -oUserKnownHostsFile=build_known_hosts -oPasswordAuthentication=no user@server
  Welcome to [...]
  user@server:~$ exit
  logout
  Connection to server closed.
  ```
- Now you need to set up the build. You can't directly use the private key as it would allow anyone to log into the target server, so we will simmetrically encrypt the private key. You can use something like

  ```
  $ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in build_id_rsa -out build_id_rsa.enc
  enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
  Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
  ```
- Add build_id_rsa.enc and build_known_hosts to your project
- Add the symmetric password to the .travis.yml using

  ```
  travis encrypt 'PASS=yoursymmetricpassword' --add
  ```

  so you should get

  ```
  env:
    global:
    - secure: [...]
  ```

  added to your .travis.yml
- Now modify your .travis.yml to upload the artefacts.

  ```
  before_script:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -d -pass env:PASS -in build_id_rsa.enc -out build_id_rsa ; chmod 600 build_id_rsa
  script:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == 'false' && "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == 'master' ]] ; then your_build && scp -q -i build_id_rsa -oPasswordAuthentication=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=build_known_hosts artefact user@server:path/ ; else ; your_build ; fi
  after_script:
  - rm -rf build_id_rsa
  ```

Caveats: Make sure you understand all the steps as I've probably made some typos and the mechanism is not super-secure: Includes writing the private key in the Travis VM file system during the build. There are many ways in which something could go wrong and that file could get exposed, giving access to your server.